# Put-Call-Parity of Asian Options

Tags: probability, finance, economics

I could need some help with deriving the put-call-parity for asian options.

Let $S_t$ be the price of the underlying asset at time $t$ and set $Y_t = \int_0^t S_t dt$. Then the payoff of an asian option at expiration date $T$ is

$Payoff = \left( \frac{Y_T}{T} - K \right)^+$.

Now let $C(t)$ be the asian call value, $P(t)$ the asian put value. Then, if i 'm correct, at expiration date i get the equation:

$C(T)-P(T) = \left( \frac{Y_T}{T} - K \right)^+ - \left( K - \frac{Y_T}{T} \right)^+ = \frac{Y_T}{T} - K$

Now if I discount this back to $t=0$ I get

$C(0)-P(0) = e^{-rT} \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{Y_T}{T} - K \right]$

My Question: Is this correct? Can I say more about this expectation?

Comment: It is correct. About the expectation, assume the asset is priced in the same currency as the final settlement currency, you can deduce $\mathbb{E}(S_t)$ from the market forwards of the asset. In that case, the expectation only depends on the interest rates and not on the volatilities.

Comment: Many thank achille, you saved my day ;). If we assume $S_t$ is a geom. BM, i 'm not sure if one can say more about that average $\frac{Y_T}{T}$? How does $\mathbb{E}[S_t]$ help in this case? Or is $\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{Y_T}{T} \right] = \mathbb{E}[S_t]$?

Comment: $$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{Y_T}{T}\right] = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \mathbb{E}\left[S_t\right] dt$$ Please note that the last expectation is expectation against the "probability distribution of all possible history" at the time of maturity $T$. For geom BM and pricing/settlement in same currency, the expectation will be the same as the one computed from market forwards (assuming no arbitrage is possible)